# Embed Graphics2D into itext without absolute positioning

Tags: java, pdf, itext, graphics2d

I'm creating PDFs with iText (LGPL) which include some Text and self-drawn (Graphics2D) images.

My current solution is to draw the images on a BufferedImage and then include it in the PDF, which has several drawbacks:
If printed, the images just look ugly, a way to circumvent this is to use larger images, and with 3000*3000 it looks ok. But this leads to the next problem: time. It takes several seconds to compress one image (I haven’t found a way to disable it, and files would be huge without compression).

PdfGraphics2d from iText looks good, but has one major drawback: it’s only able to draw to the background of the PDF, and there seems to be no way to wrap it in some kind of element.

Is there a way to draw on a PDF without having to use absolute positions? I’m using Graphics2d because it’s used also to provide a preview in the UI.

Comment: Post the code you are tried.

Comment: Which exactly? All examples only cover absolute positioning, and there i havent found a way to draw on an Element (i.e. PdfTemplate which i assumed to be exactly what i need doesnt extend Element) I dont think its possible, i just want to be sure.

Comment: As explained in the documentation, you can wrap a `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object without losing any of the vector image's quality. Also: please upgrade! You're using a version of iText you should no longer use for reasons explained here: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Works. Thanks! If you post it as answer, ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object without losing any of the vector image's quality. In most cases, you'll use the `Image` object to add raster images to a PDF document as an **Image XObject**. However, in this case, the `PdfTemplate` will be added as a **Form XObject** using its original vector data. Another situation when this happens, is when you add a WMF file; such as file is converted into PDF syntax automatically.